# Linux sed regex replace with capture groups

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I have a file containing directory entries in the following format:

```
<item><ln></ln><fn>Some person</fn><ct>07123456789</ct><sd>37</sd><rt>1</rt><bw>1</bw></item>
```

I would like to use `sed` to search for any where `<ct>` is an 11 digit number and where `<bw>1</bw>`. I would like to change the line above like so:

```
<item><ln></ln><fn>Some person</fn><ct>07123456789</ct><sd>37</sd><rt>1</rt><bw>0</bw></item>
```

(if it isn't obvious I have changed `<bw>`= 0)

I have tried the following in `sed` but it does not match:

```
sed -E 's/(.+<ct>\d{11}.+<bw>)1(<\/bw><\/item>)/\10\2/g' test-directory.xml
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `sed` with 2 capture groups:

```bash
sed -E 's~(.*<ct>[0-9]{11}</ct>.*<bw>)1(</bw>.*)~\10\2~' file

<item><ln></ln><fn>Some person</fn><ct>07123456789</ct><sd>37</sd><rt>1</rt><bw>0</bw></item>
```

**More Info:**

- `(.*<ct>[0-9]{11}</ct>.*<bw>)`: Match and capture any text followed by `<ct>11-digits</ct>` followed by any text followed by `<bw>` in capture group #1
- `1`:
- `(</bw>.*)`: Match `</bw>` followed by anything in capture group #2

PS: This assumes `<ct>` tag appears before `<bw>` tag in same line. For more refined control over XML better to use a XML parser instead of shell utilities.

---

If `<bw>` tag position is not fixed then you may use this `sed` solution:

```bash
sed -E '\~<ct>[0-9]{11}</ct>~ s~(.*<bw>)1(</bw>.*)~\10\2~' file
```

Comment: You could do this with a single capture group `sed -E '\~<ct>[0-9]{11}</ct>~s/(<bw>)[0-9]+/\10/' input_file`

Comment: Yes agreed but matching closing tag `</bw>` validates it a bit

Comment: Not had a chance to test this, will do today - @HatLess any chance you could explain your solution? looks interesting!

Comment: `<bw>` is fixed so no need to mitigate for that moving around

Comment: @btongeorge My solution is very similar as anubhava's second solution hence why I did not provide it as an answer. The only difference is that he matches the closing tag

Comment: Thanks to all - I implemented the first solution (with `<bw>` in fixed location) and it worked great.

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`(in case you are ok with it) you could try following GNU `awk` solution, written and tested in GNU `awk` with shown samples. Simple explanation would be, using `match` function of `awk` program where using regex `(.*<ct>[0-9]{11}<\/ct>.*<bw>)([0-9]+)(<\/bw>.*)` which creates 3 capturing group in it(to be used later on) and stores values of those as per capturing group number it will create index of items in array named `arr`. Once its done then printing only required part(changing any digits with 0 which is coming before `</bw>`).

```
awk '
match($0,/(.*<ct>[0-9]{11}<\/ct>.*<bw>)([0-9]+)(<\/bw>.*)/,arr){
  print arr[1]"0"arr[3]
}
' Input_file
```

Here is the [Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/BE8ZeA/1) for above shown regex.